# How can I make a method sends signal when it is called?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a very simply GUI. It have only a text box and a button on it. When the button is clicked a dll is called.

Now I want to update text box in the GUI when a specific method in the dll is called.

How can i do that?

Comment: Can you change the DLL's code or is it 3rd-Party?

Comment: And by "signal", what do you mean? Like an event?

Comment: Either obtain the source code to the DLL, or start doing some serious reverse engineering. The first, probably the best solution.

Comment: Not a bad question. What's up with all the down votes?

Comment: Is anybody else calling the dll method besides your button?

Comment: @TaW no, just the button.

Comment: And why not do your updates to the textbox in the buttonclick along with the dll call?

Comment: @TaW I can't because when I click the button for a single time then  a process begin in an iteration. I update the text box for specific iteration step however I want to update also when a specific method is called. Let me explain this way, when I start click let say I begin to throw darts, for every 10 shot I print total score. I ask if I can update the text box if a dart goes off target.

Comment: Where is the iteration happening? In the DLL? Then you should think about adding a call-back function to it to notify about its progress. Or in the button? then you may want to post the button code to your original question. Maybe the grumpy mods will consider lifting their ban then ;-)

Comment: Loop is in the buttonclick method. Anyway I think "Raising and subscribing an event" will help me.

Can you little explain call back thing? What keywords shoul I look for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *can* modify the source of DLL , solution is easy enough: just create an event and on a method call raise an event. Caller can subscribe to that event, so any time someone calls that method, caller will be notified. Just basic concepts naturally.

If you *can not*, it becomes complicated, as afak there is no other option as  `CLR Profiling Api` to, in some way, inject "yourself" inside code. But I'm not even sure if that API provides any kind of notification to consumer.

Comment: @maxc900: search for "raising and subscribing to events in C#". it's easy, much easier then phd :)